# ELI5: What is the data type of `int *p[]`

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, types

I don't understand what the datatype of this is. If its a pointer or an array. Please explain in simple terms. To quote what was in the book-

> If you want to pass an array of pointers into a function, you can use the same method that you use to pass other arrays—simply call the function with the array name without any indexes. For example, a function that can receive array x looks like this:

```
void display_array(int *q[])
{
  int t;
  for(t=0; t<10; t++)
    printf("%d ", *q[t]);
}
```

> Remember, q is not a pointer to integers, but rather a pointer to an array of pointers to
>   integers. Therefore you need to declare the parameter q as an array of integer pointers,
>   as just shown. You cannot declare q simply as an integer pointer because that is not
>   what it is.

cite: C++: The Complete Reference, 4th Edition by Herbert Schildt, Page 122-123

Comment: Maybe [this site](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*p%5B%5D) helps. The book is wrong by the way, `p` is not a pointer.

Comment: @nwp: `p` is a pointer if this declaration occurs in a function parameter. But then the book is wrong in a different way; `p` is then a pointer to a pointer (which may be the first of an array of pointers).

Comment: When the `[]` are used as a function parameter, they are absolutely the same as a `*`: `void display_array(int *q[])` is the same as `void display_array(int **q)`; `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is the same as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`; `void foo(int a[])` is the same as `void foo(int *a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it's built up:

- `int` is the *type* "int".
- `int*` is the *type* "pointer to int"
- `int* []` is the *type* "array (of unknown bound/length) of pointer to int"
- `int* p[]` is the *declaration* of a variable or parameter named *p* of the type above.

Comment: What you are failing to mention is that you _can't_ declare an array with empty size. Apart from a few special cases.

Answer (score 3):

> ... pointer to an array of pointers to integers

No it's not. `q` is the type `int *[]`. Which is an invalid (or possibly incomplete, depending on context) type in C++, and only valid in some places in C. Arrays must have a size.

The type `int *[]` is an (unsized) array of pointers to `int`. It is itself not a pointer.

---

The confusion probably comes from the fact that an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

For example, lets say we have this array:

```
int a[20];
```

When plain `a` is used, it decays to a pointer to its first element: `a` is equal to `&a[0]`.

Comment: I'm sorry but [C++ has a dark corner to offer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Arrays_of_unknown_bound) yet again :)

Comment: @Quentin The big point there is that unbounded arrays are *incomplete*. You can have *declarations* using them, but you can't *define* an array without the size.

Comment: Re “Arrays must have a size”: Well, maybe somewhere, but not necessarily inside a translation unit. You can even use the contents of an object with incomplete type: `extern int *p[]; int foo(void) { return *p[3]; }` is strictly conforming C and compiles without complaint.

Answer (score 2):

```
   int *p[]
//      ^
```

**p** is

```
   int *p[]
//       ^^
```

p is **an array of unspecified size** *(possibly illegal, depends on context)*

```
   int *p[]
// ^^^^^
```

p is an array of unspecified size of **pointers to int**

Meaning each element of `p` is a pointer:

```
int foobar = 42;
p[0] = NULL;
p[1] = &foobar;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand what the datatype of this is

If it's any comfort, neither does the author of the book you are reading.

> Remember, q is not a pointer to integers, but rather a pointer to an array of pointers to integers.

This is [bullschildt](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/bullschildt.html).

- *Before* adjustment of parameters, `q` is an array of pointers to integers.
- *After* adjustment of parameters, `q` is a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to integers. Equivalent to `int** q`, a pointer to pointer to an `int`.

Nowhere is it "a pointer to an array of pointers to integers". That would have been  `int* (*q)[]`.

I would advise to stop reading that book.

The key here is that any array that is part of a parameter list of a function, gets adjusted ("decays") into a pointer to the first element. So it doesn't matter if you type `int* q[666]` or `int* q[]`, either will be silently replaced by the compiler with `int**` "behind the lines".

This is actually the reason why we can write `[]` in a parameter list - normally an empty array would be an incomplete type that can't be used before completion elsewhere. But since parameters always get adjusted, they are never of array type, and it doesn't matter that the original type was incomplete.

Comment: @DavidBowling Sadly, it's a well-known term that was invented many decades ago. And yet here we are, still suffering from these books.